# What to call a reservation that turns into a booking automatically in the future?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose, you want to book a hotel room.

1. After seven days the reservation expires and you have to manually confirm the reservation. Hence, I call it an "expiring reservation".
2. After seven days the reservation also expires but is turned into a booking automatically. One would have to manually cancel the reservation before the due date.

I want a word for the second kind of reservation that conveys the meaning of "turns into a booking in the future unless you opt out". I thought about "future booking", yet I don't find it ideal. (It's not a booking, if you opt out there are no fees involved.)

I want a short wording that makes the distinction between these two types of reservations as clear as possible.

Comment: Maybe more suited to [ux.se]

Comment: I think it is an "unconfirmed reservation".

Comment: Just to clarify - there's nothing inherent about a booking that means fees must exists if cancelling. So while I don't know the context of your problem and why you need to differentiate the two concepts by name and not by explanation/disclaimer - I'd personally go with booking for your second case.

Comment: I expect any reservation to be of the second kind unless otherwise specified.

Comment: #1 already has a different name: [ticket reconfirmation](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7808).

Comment: One possibility is **vesting reservation**, consonant with this definition of the verb _vest_ from _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_: "to grant or endow with a particular authority, right, or property {the plan _vests_ workers with pension benefits after 10 years of service}." In your example, what vests after the grace period is the contract for a reservation, which becomes binding instead of revocable.

Comment: @SvenYargs Why as a comment and not as an answer?

Comment: @k0pernikus: It's a comment because it suggests a phrase that you might use—not a phrase that (as far as I know) anyone actually does use. And the only research I did was to look up the relevant sense of _vest_ in a dictionary—so not a full-fledged answer by any means.

Comment: You can consider it (#2) to be a confirmed booking from the start, with a 7-day *cooling-off period*.

Answer (score 2):

As the question was about the second type, I am listing in reverse order.
**2)** Options for a reservation that automatically changes to a booking:

- automatic confirmation
- automatic guaranteed reservation
- automatic non-guaranteed reservation
- automatic booking
- confirmed future booking (may imply the booking is more assured than you wish)

Options which appear to be hotel industry standards

- [cooperate](http://hotelstudies608743.blogspot.com/2010/01/types-of-reservation.html) reservation
- [contract](http://www.hotelnewsnow.com/Articles/6217/Hotel-Industry-Terms-to-Know) room or reservation

Including '*automatic*' should be enough to make clear that a difference between the reservation types exists, even if the user has to click or read more to discover what that difference is. Note that at least in the United States, if the words '*guaranteed reservation*' is used or a credit card is taken to process such a booking there may be legal requirements such as listed below in the NOLO quote.

**1)** I understand you have settled on the term "expiring reservation". Please note that at least to clients in the United States, the term "expiring" could imply that the thing in question would appear to be in the process of expiring *now* rather than later. If the reservation wording is clear on the contract details of course this *may* not be an issue.
Other common terms for reservation types:

- [guaranteed reservation](https://www.nolo.com/dictionary/guaranteed-reservation-term.html)

  > *"A hotel or rental car reservation secured by a credit card number. In exchange for your card number, the hotel or rental agency promises to have a room or vehicle for you no matter when you show up. If you have a guaranteed reservation with a hotel, it [legally] must provide you with a room, either at that hotel or at another comparable establishment."*
- [non-guaranteed reservation](http://hotelstudies608743.blogspot.com/2010/01/types-of-reservation.html)

  > The room reservation is confirmed but there is no legal requirement of advanced deposit. When the reservation is confirmed, the hotel agrees to hold the room until the agreed upon reservation cancellation hour and date. After the cancellation hour, the room is released and the reservation is automatically cancelled.

References:
https://www.nolo.com/dictionary/guaranteed-reservation-term.html
http://hotelstudies608743.blogspot.com/2010/01/types-of-reservation.html
http://www.hotelnewsnow.com/Articles/6217/Hotel-Industry-Terms-to-Know

Answer (score -1):

There is a term in use for the first class, and you're on the right track.

For something that automatically expires, the term **self-expiring** is used.

From the [dezeem](http://www.dezeen.com/2013/08/14/self-expiring-packaging-by-kanupriya-and-gautam-goel/) site:

> 14 Aug 2013 - Self Expiring is a packaging material for medicinal
>   products that visually 'self expires' over a fixed period of time.

And from [Visitor Pass Solutions](https://www.visitorpasssolutions.com/About_Us/About_our_Product_Visitor_Pass_Solutions/Self_Expiring_Solutions/):

> For extra security, put a time limit on your visitors with our
>   self-expiring badges

For your second type of reservation, the term **self-confirming** also exists; using it here would require a broadening of the usual sense (bringing about the prophesied result), but I think would be perfectly clear in your context (self-confirming reservation: automatically becoming a booking).

Comment: Yes, but OP is referring to a reservation that does nor expire but can be cancelled.

Comment: The question is about the difference between `self-expiring` and `expiring into becoming a booking`.